# How do you add a field that gives the chronological number value of each lesson for a specific student?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am making a prototype for a database in Access. I have a student table, and a lesson table. one student can have many lessons. I want a field that says which lesson that was for the student, e.g. 'lesson 3'. I am very open to advice on making new tables, queries, fields, etc, my database is a prototype, so if you think it would be better to completely change it, then I am open to suggestions.

Comment: How is the lesson numbering figured out? The order it which they enrolled? The order in which the lessons start?

Comment: Would like to know what table you'd like that column in - realistically you could be asking to find the number of lessons each student has taken in the student table or what number lesson that was for each student in the lessons table. Also what can you join the two on? I assume something like student ID?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for but I would change the relationship ship to a many to many relationship facilitated by a join table between student and lessons.  The join table would have a composite primary key made of the two foreign keys referencing the student and lessons primary keys.  I would do this because at any time a student can have many lessons but a lesson can also have many students present at any time. 
Then in the lesson table you may want to add the chronological number of the lesson as a column named ChronoNumber or something to that effect.  The ChronoNumber may repeat a bit but at least you will be able to use the one table to facilitate all the students and all the lessons.

Comment: But you already can find the students in any given lesson by just looking at the lesson primary key and counting the students. I think a one to many relationship makes perfect sense it all just depends on what he's trying to do. He could be asking to find the number of lessons each student has taken in the student table or what number lesson that was for each student in the lessons table.